# Inclined Plane with friction

Tags: modelica

I just started using Modelica (Dymola) and tried most of the tutorials as well.

Now I just wanted to build a simple "Inclined Plane with Friction" model.
There are some examples, like

- Mechanics.Translational.Components.MassWithStopAndFriction
- Mechanics.Translational.Examples.Friction

but I do not know how to "rotate" these in 2 Dimensions. I want to let a mass slide on an inclined plane under the influence of gravity...

My goal is, to evaluate the critical angle of inclination when stiction becomes friction...

I hope you understand my problem and I am looking forward to your answers.

Answer (score 0):

This is a good point.  I'm not sure I know if a good way to handle this.  You could simulate the force that would cause the block to slide by using a simple force and making the magnitude sin(theta)*m*g.  But the problem is simulating the effect that inclining the plan has on the normal force (i.e. cos(theta)*m*g) so that the friction force (mu*cos(theta)*m*g) is computed properly.  You might have to create your own models I'm afraid.